# Data accessible from other systems with the same UID?

Tags: ext4, chmod, acl

Say I've got two dual-boot Linux systems on the same computer. Both share the same `/home` mount point.
Amy, the only user on system 1, has a UID of 1000. She stored some files in `/home/amy`. Bill, the only user on system 2, also has a UID of 1000. Can Bill access `/home/amy` without any restrictions?
Also, is this situation even worse on a portable HDD formatted to ext4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Bill will access Amy's files with no restrictions. Unix security is based on UID, not user names. If your HDD ext4 partition contains sensitive data, you may want to encrypt it as any root user on a foreign machine may access it anyway.